# How to generate unique id for each instance of C# project template?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, guid

I want to develop a C# template for visual studio. I need to assign a different GUID for each project generated with this template (it should remain the same for multiple builds of the same project). I believe there is already some mechanism to do that ([assembly: Guid] attribute or project guid I don't know). So what is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the VS install directory, then drill into Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ClassLibrary.zip.  You'll find the template version of assemblyinfo.cs there.  Copy that to your own template .zip file.  Note that 1033 is English, it may a different code page on yours.

The relevant line in the file is

```
 [assembly: Guid("$guid1$")]
```

The IDE replaces the parts of the file between $dollars$ with an appropriate substitution when you create a project from your template.  Template parameters are [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).